# C# Help with OR checking both sides

Tags: c#

This should be an easy question hopefully but as a rookie I don't know the answer.

In the code below if ignorePath is true I don't want to enter the if statement even if tempPath is not null and tempPath length is not 0. I thought a single | would do this but it appears not to.

```
if (((tempPath != null) && (tempPath.Length != 0)) | ignorePath == false)
{

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Anything wrong with `!ignorePath`? And `usePath` (or whatever is the appropriate inversion of "ignore" here) might be even better as `!ignore...` could be considered double negation.

Comment: `|` is the bitwise OR operator.

Comment: `||` is the logical OR operator.

Comment: We don't want OR here at all. *All* of those conditions have to be met in order for the statement to evaluate to true, so you want to use AND (`&&`) instead. But yes, Uwe is correct: `&` and `|` are the **bitwise** operators. Double them to get the **logical** operators (which is what you want in an `if` statement): `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the following code would be clearer:

```
if ((!ignorePath) && (tempPath != null) && (tempPath.Length != 0))
{
    // do something here
}
```

First you verify that `ignorePath` is false (because you don't want the code to execute when it is true), then you check that `tempPath` is not `null` and that its length is non-zero.

The advantage here is that you've moved the check of the `ignorePath` variable to be *first*. Since it is apparently the most important thing to you (it overrides the other two conditions), it ought to come first for clarity and readability (and performance, I suppose, but that hardly matters here).

---

Remember that there's no reason to check Boolean types against the literal values `true` or `false`. An `if` statement already evaluates whether the value of the statement inside the `( )` is `true` or `false`. Specifying it explicitly is just redundant.

The only problem I see with the above code is that `!ignorePath` is a little difficult to read. It creates a double negative, as you're "not-ignoring" something. What exactly does that mean? That's why most coding standards (including Microsoft's recommended standards for .NET) encourage you to name Boolean variables with *positive* grammar. I'd call that variable something like `checkPath`, instead.

Comment: oh! how many parenthesis! the problem is easier to solve! without thousands of parenthesis!

Comment: @Farzin: Not without sacrificing readability it's not. Breaking each statement up into a logical chunk is important, it makes it clear that the `if` statement contains 3 separate pieces. One could choose to write it without the parentheses, but I wouldn't write it that way in *my* code.

Comment: Thank you Cody, this works perfectly. Thank you all for your suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand clearly, when `ignorePath` is `true`, you want to ignore the `if` statement? So there's no need to OR, this is third AND condition.

```
if (ignorePath == false && tempPath != null && tempPath.Length != 0)
{

}
```

Comment: if ignorePath was true also checks for tempPath!

Comment: Sure, `ignorePath` should be checked first to make it more readable, but functionally it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: C# evaluates conditions from left to right if no parenthesis provided,

Comment: But parenthesis wouldn't change anything here. Logical operator `&&` has lower priority than `!=` and `==`, regardless of parenthesis. Parenthesis can be useful when mixing AND and OR's, but I can see no reason to use it with AND only.

Answer (score 0):

if (!ignorePath || ((tempPath != null) && (tempPath.Length != 0)))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tempPath is a string, so you might write your code like:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempPath) && !ignorePath)
{

}
```

You want the **and** `&&` operator, since you want both conditions to be true to enter the if.

Answer (score -1):

Change it like this :

```
if (!ignorePath)
   if ((tempPath != null) && (tempPath.Length != 0)))
{
}
```

or

```
if (!ignorePath && ((tempPath != null) && (tempPath.Length != 0)))
{
}
```

Comment: Why split it up into two separate `if` statements when a single one will do the job?

Comment: Amazing how your answers morph so drastically over their lifetime. And morph in a direction so similar to mine, too! But no accusations here; far be it for me to assume anything.

Comment: But it is much less readable with two `if`s, especially without curly braces. And what are all those `()` braces for - they are redundant here.

Comment: @Cody I don't know why you are looking for answers like yours! maybe you are copying answers from other's post!

Comment: @Farzin, everyone can check the answer's revisions and see what was your answer when Cody submits his...